# loading two images in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

This is my code for loading two images, but now there is a problem, and the image appears in the second part when I click on the first button. where is the problem from? I want two parts to be completely separate.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display:none">
    {!! Form::label('pic',' img : ') !!}
    @if(!empty($user->shop_img))
        <img src="{{ url('upload/avatars').'/'.$user->img }}" id="output" width="150" onclick="select_file()">
    @else
        <img src="{{ url('images/pic_1.jpg') }}" id="output" width="150" onclick="select_file()">
    @endif
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="picshop" id="picshop" onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display:none">
    {!! Form::label('picshop',' imgshop : ') !!}
    @if(!empty($user->shop_img))
        <img src="{{ url('upload/shop').'/'.$user->shop_img }}" id="outputshop" width="150" onclick="select_file()">
    @else
        <img src="{{ url('images/pic_1.jpg') }}" id="output" width="150" onclick="select_file()">
    @endif
</div>

<script>
    select_file = function () {
        document.getElementById('pic').click();
    };
    loadFile=function (event) {
        var render=new FileReader;
        render.onload=function ()
        {
            var output=document.getElementById('output');
            output.src=render.result;
        };
        render.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
</script>

<script>
    select_file=function () {
        document.getElementById('picshop').click();
    };
    loadFile=function (event) {
        var render=new FileReader;
        render.onload=function ()
        {
            var output=document.getElementById('outputshop');
            output.src=render.result;
        };
        render.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is caused because you put the same name in the functions that are supposed to be distinct.

You should rename them to something like `select_file1`, `select_file2`, `loadFile1`, and `loadFile2`, respectively.

Also, the second `img` of the second `.form-group` has an ID with the value `output`. Maybe you'd like to set it to `outputshop`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears, because you override the functions defined in the first `<script>` element as soon as the second `<script>` element is parsed by the browser.

There are two possible solutions to this. The first solution is pointed out by @emanuelpoletto: Make the names of the functions unique and add the appropriate `onclick` and `onchange` listeners to the elements you want them to be.

A cleaner solution would be to choose a different way of writing with just a single `<script>` element.

```js
loadFile = function (sourceId, outputId) { // ID of source and output given on click
    var reader = new FileReader();         // Always use () with constructors
    var input = document.getElementById(sourceId); // Get the source element
    var output = document.getElementById(outputId);// Get the destination element
    reader.onload = function () {  // Make FileReader ready
      output.src = render.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // Read the file
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" style="display:none">
  {!! Form::label('pic',' img : ') !!}
  @if(!empty($user->shop_img))
      <img src="{{ url('upload/avatars').'/'.$user->img }}" id="output" width="150" onclick="loadFile('pic', 'output')">
  @else
      <img src="{{ url('images/pic_1.jpg') }}" id="output" width="150" onclick="loadFile('pic', 'output')">
  @endif

</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="file" name="picshop" id="picshop" style="display:none">
  {!! Form::label('picshop',' imgshop : ') !!}
  @if(!empty($user->shop_img))
      <img src="{{ url('upload/shop').'/'.$user->shop_img }}" id="outputshop" width="150" onclick="loadFile('picshop', 'outputshop')">
  @else
      <img src="{{ url('images/pic_1.jpg') }}" id="outputshop" width="150" onclick="loadFile('picshop', 'outputshop')">
  @endif

</div>
```

Note the changes made to the HTML, they are important. There are no more `onchange` handlers, which lets you get rid of the `select_file` function. The `loadFile` function now does all the work and it receives the values of the `id` attributes of the source and the output nodes. It creates a new `FileReader`, looks up the input and output elements and reads the file from the input node.